# How to add an image to UIBarButtonItem?

Tags: objective-c, ios, uibarbuttonitem, navigationbar

I created a custom button and applied it to the UIbarbuttonitem.
There is no error but nothing is shown on the navigation bar:(
This is my code-

```
    //create a custom button
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"TESTButton.png"];
    UIButton *myCustomButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    myCustomButton.bounds = CGRectMake( 0, 0, image.size.width, image.size.height );    
    [myCustomButton setImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [myCustomButton addTarget:nil action:@selector(goBack:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];


    UIBarButtonItem *button = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:myCustomButton];
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = button;
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleDefault;

    [button release];
    [myCustomButton release];
    [image release];
    [navID release];
```

Anybody who can fix my code? :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From [the docs:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIBarButtonItem_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

```
initWithImage:style:target:action:
```

Try that.

Comment: Like this?    
    UIBarButtonItem *button = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:image style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(goBack:)];
   
Stil not working.. no error, but nothing is shown :(

Comment: Make sure your image isn't returning as nil.

Answer (score 3):

To set ANY image with right coloring, use UIButton, set "image for state" and then create **UIBarButtonItem** with **customView**

```
UIImage *btnImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"button"];
UIButton *btn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
btn.bounds = CGRectMake( 0, 0, btnImage.size.width, btnImage.size.height );
[btn addTarget:self action:@selector(action:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
[btn setImage:btnImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
_buttonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:btn];
```

Answer (score 2):

One of the Simplest Way is :

```
UIBarButtonItem *button2 = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"backk.png"] style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(backBtn:)];
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = button2;
```

Action Method:

```
- (IBAction)backBtn:(id)sender
{
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```